# NEST async call

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, elasticsearch, nest, nest2

According to [this link](https://www.elastic.co/blog/ga-release-of-nest-2-0-our-dot-net-client-for-elasticsearch), NEST 2.0 internals just moved to a fully fledged async/await implementation.

Does this mean that NEST 2.0 internally works in a complete asynchronous fashion?

If not, shall we use async when calling the NEST API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The internals for asynchronous calls have been rewritten from using a Task Parallel Library (TPL) based approach to using async/await. This made it easier to simplify the approach to exception and error handling, although both the old TPL and new async/await approaches were both asynchronous (as far as async methods are exposed).

Let's take `GetAsync<T>()` as an example. The pipeline of calls are:

1. `IElasticClient.LowLevelDispatch.GetDispatchAsync<GetResponse<T>>()`
2. `IElasticLowLevelClient.GetAsync<T>()` with route values extracted from the previous call
3. `IElasticLowLevelClient.DoRequestAsync<T>()`, a general request dispatching method which calls the `ITransport`'s request async method
4. `ITransport.RequestAsync<T>()`, which for the default `Transport<TConnectionSettings>` will:

   1. create an `IRequestPipeline` using the `IRequestPipelineFactory`. The default is `RequestPipeline`
   2. `RequestPipeline.SniffAsync()` on first pool usage if the `IConnectionPool` supports sniffing. A `WaitAsync()` is performed on a `SemaphoreSlim` here to block whilst the first sniff happens.
   3. A node is selected from the cluster with the following calls applied:

      1. `RequestPipeline.SniffOnStaleClusterAsync()` in the event the cluster has been marked as stale previously
      2. `RequestPipeline.PingAsync()` to ensure the node can be pinged
      3. make the call to Elasticsearch with `RequestPipline.CallElasticsearchAsync<TReturn>()` which will use the `IConnection` passed to `ConnectionSettings` when creating an ElasticClient to make the request using `IConnection.RequestAsync<TReturn>()`. The default `IConnection` in .NET 4.5 + (i.e. *full fat* CLR) is `HttpConnection`. Internally, `HttpConnection` uses `HttpWebRequest` to make the actual request:

         1. get the request stream with `HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStreamAsync()`
         2. write data to the request stream if necessary using `PostData<T>.WriteAsync()`
         3. make the HTTP request with `HttpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync()`
         4. build a meaningful response from the response stream using a response builder, `ResponseBuilder<TReturn>.ToResponseAsync()`. Inside of here, the response will be deserialized to `TReturn`; for most responses that are json, this will use `IElasticsearchSerializer.DerserializeAsync<TReturn>()` to deserialize the response. For the default json serializer that uses Json.NET, there is no asynchronous deserialization method so the async version simply wraps the synchronous deserialization call.

That's a brief summary of what happens, hope it helps :)